# Book about time portals inside an asteroid in Earth orbit

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this book many years ago and it had a nice plot. For the life of me I can't remember the name or author so I need help.

Story: one asteroid shaped object appears close to Earth orbit or in the Sol system.

People get on board and start exploring. They find machines/computers that can teach them anything in a very short time (languages, crafts etc).

Towards the end, something happens and one of the characters goes into a long tunnel where he/she opens a portal in time with the help of a device he/she has.

In the epilogue it states that he has been transported back in time to Egypt.  I think there were no pyramids.

Sorry for being brief but this is all I remember. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologize for being brief.  I think you did a good job listing some easily recognizable details without unnecessary extraneous info.  i.e. from what you described, I am 99.99% sure terdon is correct and it is Eon.  Had terdon not suggested it, I would have.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could this be [Greg Bear's *Eon*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/840278.Eon)? A mysterious artifact arrives in Earth orbit; it is a long cylinder. As the book progresses, the main characters start traveling down the *Way*, the inside of the cylinder, where they find various wonders, including "portals" that allow them to travel in time and between alternate universes I think.

If I recall correctly, one of the characters does indeed end up in an alternate ancient Egypt but I don't remember if the pyramids were there or not.

Comment: This was the book that I immediately thought of as well.

Comment: Definitely Eon. Actually, at the end it's Patricia Luisa Vasquez who gets transported - not back in time, but to an alternative present where the Egyptian culture is still dominant, and there are *too many* pyramids.

Comment: ty so much... it has to be Eon coz the name rings a bell and the cylinder sounds more right to me than an asteroid as i stated previously.

Comment: No, you're right, it *is* an asteroid that appears in Earth orbit.  The asteroid has been hollowed out, and segmented into seven chambers; the seventh chamber "goes on forever" and is, in fact, the Way.