Book about a wormhole found inside the Moon
Back in the '80's, I read a book that begins with astronauts exploring caves in the Moon and finding one tunnel that has no end. They discover that it is a tunnel through space and time, maybe even other universes and they set out to explore it. They discover that there are a tremendous number of "gates" that they can access, but they can also "install" new gates. An enemy tries to destroy them by opening a gate in the heart of a star, which causes the plasma to flood the tunnel (or wormhole). The astronauts try accelerating their spaceship to near light speed, which causes some sort of "wake" that pushes the plasma down the tunnel and back through the open gate. At the end of the book, one of the astronauts gets marooned inside a gate to a world much like Earth in the past and becomes a king. What is the name of this book?

Sounds like Eon by Greg Bear.  I think this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37739/book-about-time-portals-inside-an-asteroid-in-earth-orbit/37746#37746.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

This question is similar to: Book about time portals inside an asteroid in Earth orbit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RohitGupta - our meta policy is to only close story-id questions as duplicates if they both have an accepted answer (via accept or comment).

I think this is Eon by Greg Bear. An asteroid/spacecraft appears in deep space and settles in Earth orbit. Inside are seven large chambers, the first six containing space docks, storage, various biomes, and cities.  The seventh chamber extends forever and is called the Way.
All down the length of the Way there are gateways to other places/universes. An enemy species called the Jarts open a gate to a star to use the plasma as a weapon.  Our protagonists use a city built to travel down the Way as a counter-weapon by accelerating to high speed and using the resulting pressure wave to seal the gates.
Near the end of the story one of the main characters, Patricia Vasquez, gets left behind on an alternate Earth where ancient Egyptian culture came to dominate the modern world.

Was there a sequel novel?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_(novel_series)

Sorry to hijack this a bit, but do you recall if there's a part in which they ruminate on how the Way curves slightly, and that this actually makes it feel like you're looking into infinity more than a straight path would? Reading this description jogged that in my mind, but I may be misplacing it.
